# How do i create a specific one many view using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a master table and a detail table.

Question 1: I would like my view to look like this

```
master1 row, nulls
master1 row, detail1 row for master1
master1 row, detail2 row for master1
master1 row, detail3 row for master1
master2 row, nulls
master2 row, detail1 row for master2
master2 row, detail2 row for master2
```

Question 2: how can I insert a column at the beginning of each row that tells me when a row is a master only row and when a row is a master / detail row?

Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated

Comment: Research JOIN, try something , post code if you get into difficulty along with sample data and desired outcome. and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a union query. But you need to specify column names:

```
select m.pk, m.a, m.b, m.c, d.pk, d.a, d.b, d.c
from master m
join detail d on m.pk = d.fk

union all

select m.pk, m.a, m.b, m.c, null, null, null, null
from master m

order by m.pk, d.pk
```

In order to determine if a row is a master or detail, just test if `d.pk` column in the combined result is null or not.

Comment: You have FAR too much experience to NOT be highlighting the very important difference between UNION and UNION ALL. Similarly the ORDER BY clause is important and needs explanation. I suggest you also use statement terminators to encourage others to adopt them.

Comment: union should not make any difference in this case, even performance wise since SQL server can see that rows cannot be combined. I've changed to union all nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you all very much. I appreciate it